# Create Multiple User Credentials without loosing current state (logged in user) Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I want to be logged in as an admin but also wanna create user login credentials for other users. using createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method but it accidentally logging a newly created user.

**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Balfc.png)I have tried the other methods but not working in my case. Please helps me with this.
SAMPLE CODE::**

```
class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
 final _emailController = TextEditingController();
 final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
 final FirebaseFirestore _fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 bool _isLoading = false;

       final User _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
     Future<void> _createUser() async {
      try {
      setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
     });
      await _auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _emailController.text,
       password: _passwordController.text,
        )
        .then((UserCredential _user) async {
       try {
      await _fs.collection('users').doc(_user.user.uid).set({
        'email': _emailController.text,
        'password': _passwordController.text,
      }).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      _user.user.delete();
      print("User Deleted");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
       });
       }
         });
          } catch (err) {
     print("Cannot Sign Up: $err");
    setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
   }
   }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("USER--" + _currentUser.uid);
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test Screen")),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _emailController,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _passwordController,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 30),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _createUser,
          child: Text(_isLoading ? "Creating..." : "Create User"),
        ),
      ],
    ),
     ),
    );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebase Authentication there is a single signed-in user for each `FirebaseAuth` object. If you want to sign in multiple users, you will need multiple instances of the [`FirebaseAuth` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth-class.html), based on an explicit `FirebaseApp` object (instead of the default `FirebaseAuth.instance`).

Note that this is a common anti-pattern though. For example, wanting to have a administrative user in the app who can create other user accounts, is typically better handled by creating a custom back-end API (for example on Cloud Functions), where you can then the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) that is specifically made for such administrative functionality.